# AWS communication between Elastic Beanstalk and Amplify isn't working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-amplify

everyone. I hosted/deployed an AWS Elastic Beanstalk application (SpringBoot) and an Amplify application (ReactApp) and an RDS (MySQL) on AWS. Communication between SpringBoot and MySQL is working. Only the communication between frontend (React) and backend (SpringBoot) does not work. In the debug console I get the error that https (React) does not work on http (Spring). How can I change this so that the request works?

Comment: I have used the same stack - Spring/Hibernate/Mysql/RDS/Beanstalk for backend and Amplify/React for frontend. I have deployed the backend and it works fine. The frontend deployed in Anplify is not able to communicate with Backend Server in Beanstalk. Debugging in developer tools shows it as a Network Error.